# Could someone suggest a good GeoExt Tutorial?

Tags: web-mapping, geoext, references

In my research I've found these two, which are only explaining the basics.

- [Developing OGC Compliant Web Applications with GeoExt](http://workshops.opengeo.org/geoext/index.html)
- [GeoExt Workshop](ftp://ftp.itc.nl/pub/jmmgnl/GeoExt_Workshop/GeoExt-Workshop.pdf) (Pdf)

And of course the native (but short) tutorials and examples on the [GeoExt website](http://geoext.org/).

Can anyone know about other resources?

Comment: You can check this also  http://geoext.org/tutorials/

Comment: Thanks Sunil, but I've already included it in my question as "native tutorial on GeoExt website"

Comment: You'll have to explain what you mean by a "good tutorial". Are there any topics that you want to see in particular?

Comment: Most [official examples](http://geoext.org/examples.html) enough to learn if you examine code.
Because they only cover map part, don't expect lessons about ExtJS (the JavaScript Library behind)
For this, see manning book [ExtJS in Action](http://www.manning.com/garcia/) and packt publishing [Learning ExtJS 3.2](http://www.packtpub.com/learning-ext-js-32/book)

Comment: Did you try to find video tutorials on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=geoext+tutorial)?

Comment: @ThomasG77 could you post your comment as an answer so this thread stops appearing in the unanswered list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most [official examples](https://geoext.github.io/geoext3/) (link updated for OpenLayers 3 et a more recent ExtJS version e.g 6.x) are enough to learn if you examine code.

Because they only cover map part, don't expect lessons about ExtJS (the JavaScript library behind)
For this, see manning book [ExtJS in Action](http://www.manning.com/garcia/) and packt publishing [Learning ExtJS 3.2](http://www.packtpub.com/learning-ext-js-32/book)

Comment: Is  ExtJS for free? I think their site gives a trial version

Comment: You have 2 versions: one with commercial support and one with GPL licence. Go to https://www.sencha.com/legal/GPL/ to get the code (need to register) or use this copy at github https://github.com/tremez/extjs-gpl